# Was "Pastry flour for bread"

Tags: bread

I was reading the discussion about "[Pastry flour for bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77286/pastry-flour-for-bread)" and noticed that several types of flour were mentioned.  I looked at my bread flour and noticed that it says 4%.  I looked at the AP flour, a common brand, it says 3%. My question is, is it possible to add gluten to increase the protein content in the flour?  I am relatively new at making bread.  I am trying to bake an Italian recipe for crusty bread by translating the ingredients into what is available in the US.  The recipe calls for Flour 00.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Type 00 is supposedly a lot finer than normal bread flour.

Comment: "new at making bread", don't change gluten or enzyme levels of flour. "Italian recipe" use AP flour for 00.

Comment: If you give the recipe then more help might be possible.

Comment: I don't know what you read, but I doubt you can find flour as low as 3% gluten. And bread flour is certainly not 4%, it is in the 11-13 range. So check your numbers again before adding something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product available here in the United States called 'Vital Wheat Gluten'. It is 75% to 80% gluten. Added to any flour, you'll increase the gluten in the mix

Just Googled it to buy in your area